# Scrolling SWT Table is slow when running with exe4J

Tags: java, performance, swt, exe4j

I have an SWT desktop app which is distributed using install4j and runs under exe4j.

The app contains a table which displays a list of documents to be downloaded from a server. A thread handles the download and makes call-backs to select the current row and to update the row icon when the download is complete.

This works fine in my IDE (eclipse) and also when I start the app by clicking on the jar.

When running the installed package it runs much slower. This is especially noticable when I sort the table. The download schedule is then different to the order of the table items and, when the items are selected, the table is constantly scrolling up and down to show the current item. The scrolling blocks for up to 2 seconds and large parts of the table are not drawn completely. My logging suggests that the delay is in waiting for syncExec() to run.

What could this be? Why does it run fine when started directly but not in exe4j?

I mailed the support chaps and he said 'it could be related to the fact that the executable has an XP manifest while the java.exe excutable does not'.

Has anyone else had this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just heard back from support.

They suggested the following:

> Then it must be the application manifest. Actually you don't need
>   MageUI, you can edit
>
> [install4j installation directory]\resource\manifest[.64]
>
> and remove
>
> from that file, then compile the project again.

Works like a dream. Problem solved.

Must say here that I've used the support in the past and they have *always* been really helpful and prompt. Thanks!